# Why do we use "be" with "will", instead of "is" and "are"?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, linking-verbs

I want to know from a grammatical point of view why do we use *be* with *will* instead of using *is* and *are*. For example:

- Jack will **be** skydiving tomorrow. *Correct*
- Jack will **is** skydiving tomorrow. *Incorrect*

I also want to know why do we use *is*, *are*, *was*, and *were* instead of *be* in the present and past tenses. For example:

**Present Tense**

- Jack **is** skydiving today. *Correct*
- Jack **be** skydiving today. *Incorrect*

**Past Tense**

- Jack **was** skydiving yesterday. *Correct*
- Jack **be** skydiving yesterday. *Incorrect*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every verb requires its own unique complementation. For example, "make" only takes a bare-infinitive: eg. "He made me *cry*"; "Keep" only takes a participle: eg. "He keeps *crying*"; etc.

"Will" belongs to a special category of verb, the [modal verbs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb). Modal verbs (except "ought") allow only a bare-infinitive as a complement. Since the bare infinitive form of "is" and "are" is "be", it should be "will be", not "will is".

Present tense and past tense clauses are sometimes called finite clauses. Finite clauses require a main verb that is inflected for tense. So the bare-infintive (*be*), the past participle (*been*) and the present participle (*being*) are not possible.

Comment: Some other examples with 'will' would be 'will have', 'will go', etc. They are the infinitive stripped of the 'to'... thus, 'to be' 'to have', 'to go'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how one could answer that except to say, "because that's how the verb tenses are formed in English". Why do we say "is" instead of "fwacbar"? I suppose one could study the history of the language and say when the various words were invented, but that still wouldn't really tell you why. It would just tell you when.

Other languages that I know anything about have words or endings used to indicate verb tense and other grammatical constructions. Why does Latin use "-ba-" to indicate imperfect and "-bi-" to indicate future, and not the other way around? It just ... does.